# Using comparison operator to create custom field filter in Outlook C#

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have created a filter which would compare the value of custom user properties and show only emails which meets the requirement.

The filter works when I have `=` comparing value but doesn't work when I have `<=` operator.

Below is my filter.
This works.

```
string filter= $"@SQL=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}}/TimeSpent/0000001f\" = '60'"; 
Outlook.Items restrictedMails = selectedFolder.Items.Restrict(filter);
```

This won't work.

```
string filter= $"@SQL=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}}/TimeSpent/0000001f\" <= '60'"; 
Outlook.Items restrictedMails = selectedFolder.Items.Restrict(filter);
```

The code to save value in custom file is below.

```
int duration = (int)completed.Subtract(received).TotalMinutes;
try
                {
                    MailUserProperties = SelectedMail.UserProperties;
                    MailUserProperty = MailUserProperties.Add("TimeSpent", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, true, 1);
                    MailUserProperty.Value = duration;
                    SelectedMail.Save();
                }
```

Can anyone help here how to get filter working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 string filter= $"@SQL=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}}/TimeSpent/0000001f\" = '60'";
```

Here `60` is not a number, it is a string. So, basically, two strings are compared.

```
 MailUserProperty = MailUserProperties.Add("TimeSpent", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, true, 1);
```

You add a string user property and then want to apply a comparer. It makes sense only with integer values. So, the code should like the following one:

```
 MailUserProperty = MailUserProperties.Add("TimeSpent", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olInteger, true, 1);
```

And only then you may try to use the following filter:

```
 string filter= $"@SQL=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}}/TimeSpent/0000001f\" <= 60";
```

Comment: One problem I am facing after making changes is, so far I have recorded all data in "TimeSpent" user property are in text format but now I am recording in integer. I'm getting this error, `A custom field with this name but a different data type already exists. Enter a different name.` Is there any way to record new data in integer without giving new name?